# State values set from API call sometimes won't display on the page (or on form components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
get test info from api > receieve test info > store it on an object "test" > set states "test_title" and "test_desc"
> put both "test_name" and "test_desc" as values on my form
```

In getting the test info from the api:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchTest()
}, [])

const [test, setTest] = useState({})
const [test_name, setTestName] = useState("")
const [test_desc, setTestDesc] = useState("")

// Fetch Test
const fetchTest = () => {
    let test_code = params.code
    const url = ...url here...
    axios.get(url)
    .then(res => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
            setIsGettingData(false)
            setTest(res.data)

            // Set Test Name and Desc
            setTestInfo()
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response)
    })
}
```

And this for updating the `test_name` and `test_desc` which is called after receiving data from the api call:

```
// Set Test Info
const setTestInfo = () => {
    setTestName(test.name)
    setTestDesc(test.desc)
}
```

My form:

```
<form id="form_test">
     <input type="text" value={test_name} onChange={e => setTestName(e.target.value)} className="form-control mb-2" placeholder="test name" />
     <textarea className="form-control" value={test_desc} onChange={e => setTestDesc(e.target.value)} placeholder="test description"></textarea>
</form>
```

The problem is that sometimes the inputs display the actual `test_name` and `test_desc`, and sometimes it doesn't. When I console log it sometimes it says the actual values, sometimes it says undefined.

When displaying it normally on the page like `{test_name}`, it's the same thing - sometimes it shows up, sometimes it doesn't. I think this is probably because of the api call? Like there's a delay or something and I guess the DOM renders everything already before the data gets saved or receive? idk.

Any advices for this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `test` is not set yet with `res.data`

update the `test info` with `res.data` directly

```
const setTestInfo = (name, desc) => {
    if (name) {
        setTestName(name);
    } else {
        setTestName(test.name);
    }

    if (desc) {
        setTestDesc(desc)
    } else {
        setTestDesc(test.desc);
    }    
}
```

and call it from the api using `res.data` values

```
setTestInfo(res.data.name, res.data.desc)
```